# Why am I receiving a cast error when using populate() in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following error appearing through my .catch and I'm having trouble figuring it out:

```
"message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"{\n  type: 'resistance',\n  name: 'Bicep Curl',\n  duration: 20,\n  weight: 100,\n  reps: 10,\n  sets: 4\n}\" at path \"_id\" for model \"Exercise\"",
"name": "CastError",
"stringValue": "\"{\n  type: 'resistance',\n  name: 'Bicep Curl',\n  duration: 20,\n  weight: 100,\n  reps: 10,\n  sets: 4\n}\"",
"value": {
"type": "resistance",
"name": "Bicep Curl",
"duration": 20,
"weight": 100,
"reps": 10,
"sets": 4
},
"path": "_id",
"reason": {}
}
```

There's a lot of info here, so I'll start from the beginning.

I was given a seed file that looks like this. As far as I know, I should not be touching this code:

```
let mongoose = require("mongoose");
let db = require("../models");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/workout", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useFindAndModify: false
});

let workoutSeed = [
  {
    day: new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-10),
    exercises: [
      {
        type: "resistance",
        name: "Bicep Curl",
        duration: 20,
        weight: 100,
        reps: 10,
        sets: 4
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    day: new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-9),
    exercises: [
      {
        type: "resistance",
        name: "Lateral Pull",
        duration: 20,
        weight: 300,
        reps: 10,
        sets: 4
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    day: new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-8),
    exercises: [
      {
        type: "resistance",
        name: "Push Press",
        duration: 25,
        weight: 185,
        reps: 8,
        sets: 4
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    day: new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-7),
    exercises: [
      {
        type: "cardio",
        name: "Running",
        duration: 25,
        distance: 4
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    day: new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-6),
    exercises: [
      {
        type: "resistance",
        name: "Bench Press",
        duration: 20,
        weight: 285,
        reps: 10,
        sets: 4
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    day: new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-5),
    exercises: [
      {
        type: "resistance",
        name: "Bench Press",
        duration: 20,
        weight: 300,
        reps: 10,
        sets: 4
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    day: new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-4),
    exercises: [
      {
        type: "resistance",
        name: "Quad Press",
        duration: 30,
        weight: 300,
        reps: 10,
        sets: 4
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    day: new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-3),
    exercises: [
      {
        type: "resistance",
        name: "Bench Press",
        duration: 20,
        weight: 300,
        reps: 10,
        sets: 4
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    day: new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-2),
    exercises: [
      {
        type: "resistance",
        name: "Military Press",
        duration: 20,
        weight: 300,
        reps: 10,
        sets: 4
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    day: new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-1),
    exercises: [
      {
        type: "resistance",
        name: "Bench",
        duration: 30,
        distance: 2
      }
    ]
  }
];

db.Workout.deleteMany({})
  .then(() => db.Workout.collection.insertMany(workoutSeed))
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data.result.n + " records inserted!");
    process.exit(0);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

I created 2 models based on this seed, and of course the index.js file.

Workout:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var WorkoutSchema = new Schema({
    day: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    exercises: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Exercise"
        }
    ]

});

const Workout = mongoose.model("Workout", WorkoutSchema);

module.exports = Workout;
```

Exercise:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ExerciseSchema = new Schema({
    type: String,
    name: String,
    duration: Number,
    weight: Number,
    reps: Number,
    sets: Number,
    distance: Number
});

const Exercise = mongoose.model("Exercise", ExerciseSchema);

module.exports = Exercise;
```

Index.js

```
module.exports = {
    Workout: require("./Workout"),
    Exercise: require("./Exercise")
};
```

Then I ran the following code to see if I can get the json using populate:

```
app.get("/api/workouts", (req, res) => {
        db.Workout.find({})
            .populate("exercises")
            .then(dbWorkouts => res.json(dbWorkouts))
            .catch(err => res.json(err))
    });
```

However, it is giving me the error posted in the beginning. I'm not sure I understand what's wrong. If I remove populate(), I receive an empty array for exercise. Am I missing something?

Edit: Someone said to try populate("Exercises") and populate("Exercise"), and I get the same result as if populate() wasn't coded in, which looks like this:

```
[
{
"exercises": [],
"_id": "5e9d0603a58905d8f0b3a958",
"day": "2020-04-10T02:16:35.784Z"
},
{
"exercises": [],
"_id": "5e9d0603a58905d8f0b3a959",
"day": "2020-04-11T02:16:35.785Z"
},
{
"exercises": [],
"_id": "5e9d0603a58905d8f0b3a95a",
"day": "2020-04-12T02:16:35.785Z"
},
{
"exercises": [],
"_id": "5e9d0603a58905d8f0b3a95b",
"day": "2020-04-13T02:16:35.785Z"
},
{
"exercises": [],
"_id": "5e9d0603a58905d8f0b3a95c",
"day": "2020-04-14T02:16:35.785Z"
},
{
"exercises": [],
"_id": "5e9d0603a58905d8f0b3a95d",
"day": "2020-04-15T02:16:35.785Z"
},
{
"exercises": [],
"_id": "5e9d0603a58905d8f0b3a95e",
"day": "2020-04-16T02:16:35.785Z"
},
{
"exercises": [],
"_id": "5e9d0603a58905d8f0b3a95f",
"day": "2020-04-17T02:16:35.785Z"
},
{
"exercises": [],
"_id": "5e9d0603a58905d8f0b3a960",
"day": "2020-04-18T02:16:35.785Z"
},
{
"exercises": [],
"_id": "5e9d0603a58905d8f0b3a961",
"day": "2020-04-19T02:16:35.785Z"
}
]
```

Edit2: As I'm staring at this code and the data in the database, I'm realizing now that when the seed file is seeded, the subdocument for Exercises is NOT generating an ObjectID,. Is this what's casing the issue? I'm staring at my Workout model where Exercise is referenced and I'm pretty sure this is done correctly. Does anyone know if I'm missing something else?

Comment: What version of Mongoose are you using? 5.x.x ?

Comment: I'm using 5.9.9

Comment: You spelled wrong in the populate method. It should be populate('Exercises')

Comment: I tried to change it to what you said, but I receive the empty array in exercises.

Comment: Try this  `Exercise`

Comment: I get the same result, an empty array in exercises.

Edit: I'll edit the original post to reflect what it shows when typing in "Exercises" and "Exercise"

Comment: Is data storing in database?

Comment: In my Robo 3T, there is a database called workout. Inside is a collection called workouts with 10 records.

Each record has an _id, day, and exercises document. Inside the exercises document is a subdocument called 0, and opening that shows the fields that was in the seeding data. (First record has type: Resistance, name: Bicep Curl, etc.)

I use a script in my package.json for running the seed by using npm run seed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built your app and managed to reproduce the error. The issue is that you are trying to use populate on something that is already populated. What I mean by that is if you look at your db using mongoose compass you'll see that Workout already have all the data from Exercice. What you are doing is not referencing with an id but embedding it. So to make it work remove populate, import your ExerciceSchema into your Workout model file then replace

```
exercises: [
    {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Exercise"
    }
]
```

with

```
exercises: [ExerciseSchema]
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked, I guess I was over complicating it.